# angularjs in rails:add data to database and show without reloading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs

In a rails project, I add data to database by `http.post` from angularjs controller. I have below code to do this:

`RestaurantIndexCtrl.js.coffee`:

```
restauranteur.controller 'RestaurantIndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', ($scope, $location, $http) ->
$scope.restaurants = []
  $http.get('./restaurants.json').success((data) ->
    $scope.restaurants = data
  )
  $scope.addRestaurant = (test) ->
    $http({
      url: '/restaurants#create',
      method: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify({name:test}),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })

]
```

`templates/restaurants/index.html`:

```
<form ng-submit="addRestaurant(restaurant.name)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="restaurant.name">
    <button>Register</button>
</form>
<ul ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurants">
    <li><a ng-click="viewRestaurant(restaurant.id)">{{ restaurant.name }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

And below code in rails project:
`restaurants_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Now, when I comlete the `textfield` and post data to rails project, data aren't add to database until I refresh the page. When I refresh, data is add to database and show data on `index.html`.

1. I want when I copmlete the `textfield` and post to rails controller by angularjs, new data are add to database and show on `index.html` without reloding. How can I do this? The problem is exist in rails controller or angularjs code?
2. I set `unique validation` for `restaurant name`, now if I send a name that exist in database, rails controller doesn't permit to add data to database. How can I get error that rails generate and show to user in `angularjs` html code?

`Note`: I use external view for angularjs and put templates in `public` folder and then route the url by `ngRoute`.

`main.js.coffee`:

```
@restauranteur = angular.module('restauranteur', ['ngRoute'])

@restauranteur.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
  .when('/restaurants', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/restaurants/index.html',
    controller: 'RestaurantIndexCtrl'
  })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
])
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make your `create` method return the updated `@restaurants` and then update the scope in a callback on the angular side. Real rough implementation:

```
def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

    if @restaurant.save
      render json: Restaurant.all, status: 200
    else
      #whatever
    end
  end
end
```

and on the frontend:

```
$scope.addRestaurant = function(test) {
  var data = {name: test}
  $http.post('/restaurants', data).success(function(data){
    $scope.restaurants = data;
  })
}
```

Another approach to avoid the round-trip to the server is to assume success and push the new object into the existing `$scope.restaurants` on the client side. This poses some issues because of your validations.

For the validations, the errors are rendered here in your controller already:

```
format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

You'll have to add an `.error` handler to your `$http` call and set the returned data in `$scope.errors` or something to show to the user.

You will probably also want to abstract your api calls into an angular service so you can reuse the code in other parts of the application. Also consider reading up on the `resolve` attribute of `$routeProvider` and using that to resolve your data before the view is loaded.

Comment: I use your guide, but when I post data to database and data is saved, I get this error: `Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 114ms`.`ActionController::UnknownFormat(ActionController::UnknownFormat): app/controller/restaurants_controller.rb:32:in create`.

Comment: Right, you probably need to play with the data format. Look at your server logs for more information on the error. It's probably going to be something like `var data = {restaurant: {name: test}}`

Comment: Data is true, because new restaurants add correctly to database. But I don't know about `Completed 406 Not Acceptable`. and the data don't send to angularjs after save to database until I reload the page again.

Comment: was a syntax error, see my edit for the create action in your controller.

Comment: Thats right, but when I add data to database, I can just show latest record in view and `render json: Restaurant.all, status: 200` is not working and if working, data is not send from rails controller to angularjs controller. Do you know the reasons?